# How is this patentable?

Tags: us7979318

This is nothing more than a slider that calculates unit price in between standard price breaks. How exactly is this ground-breaking?

In reference to the patent: [US7979318](https://www.google.com/patents/US7979318)

Answer (score 1):

To be granted a patent has to be novel and non-obvious over the prior art at the time of filing. It **does not** have to be ground-breaking, ingenuous, the next world wonder or even commercially viable. That's simply no requierement for a patent.

In [1997 a mother of three](https://www.out-law.com/page-8119) filed a patent for online shopping carts which was auctioned of for 2.5 million pounds in London ~10 years afterwards. Retrospectively, that seems like a pretty obvious invention. Nevertheless, nobody had thought of it or if they did, nobody published it.

**An invention does not have to be ground-breaking to become a strong patent.**

Comment: A good answer. Regardless, I would have considered the cited patent as obvious. It's pretty recent.

Comment: @EricShain obvious concerning patents basically means "combining two or three prior art references produces the claimed invention". It's different than the "obvious" where we say "yes, obviously you can do that".

Comment: Obvious can also mean someone skilled in the field would find it an obvious thing to do. In this case, by 2000, having interactive controls on a web page was common practice. My guess is no one bothered to patent it and the examiner only looked at the patent art.

Comment: @EricShain that's the literal definition, but for purposes of prosecution it means what I said above because the obviousness has to be proven using prior art references. And the person skilled in the art does not act even remotely inventive, so obvious boils down to combining known features.

Comment: (Which doesn't mean this patent was necessarily non-obvious, but many times the perceived obvious patents are perceived that way because obvious in patent prosecution doesn't mean what obvious means for most people.

Comment: My point is the examiner must have limited himself to patent art, and not other sources since what is described was commonly done on the internet.

Comment: Try thinking of it with the european term of inventive step, it has less prejudice attached.

Comment: @EricShain possible. But we tend to overestimate that. I have actually never seen the described graphical representation of price-amount-relation anywhere on the internet.

Comment: The controls all existed at the time. Multiple volume pricing too. Applying the controls to pricing is the simple combination I'm referring to.

Comment: @EricShain The prior art would then be controls and multiple pricing options at predefined volumes. The invention is having varying prices for each amount by using a pricing curve. (Which is basically what the first paragraph of the description says). So you would need a reference showing the use of a continuous pricing curve instead of just a few amounts where pricing changes. (Discrete changes of pricing at certain levels vs. Continuous adaption at every amount). Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Claim 1 claims piece wise levels so it's discrete. Even if it were a mathematical function, being that it's currency you have a fixed step in Quantity vs. fixed step in cost (if only cents).

Comment: @EricShain good point. I'd argument that the difference lies in being able to represent a price for every amount contrary to prior art allowing only very few steps due to the different representation. But I wouldn't call this a sure grant. Anyways, it was granted after all. You could check the prosecution history to see what points the examiner made. But we should continue this in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61425/discussion-between-eric-shain-and-donquikong).